# How to refresh only modified rows in ALV grid?

Tags: abap, alv

I have task to refresh only modified rows in ALV grid. I know that the grid is refreshed via method

```
 CALL METHOD l_grid->refresh_table_display
  EXPORTING
    is_stable      = ls_stbl
  EXCEPTIONS
    finished       = 1
    OTHERS         = 2.
```

But it refreshes the whole grid only.

Is there any method which allows to refresh certain grid lines?

Comment: Please add a bit more context. Are you in editing or display mode?

Comment: It's a display mode only. I do some data operations/changes with selected lines when user clicks buttons on the toolbar. I must show the date changes in the ALV grid. The customer asks to refresh the selected lines only, becuase the grid can contain too much lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of the `DATA_CHANGED` event in edit mode, that is not supported.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Switching to edit mode combined with using change_data_from_inside method seem to be able to make change of certain grid lines.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem but in my scenario, i was using function module REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY. If i pass refresh command on FM it refresh whole grid display. So i solved it using user command "@REFRESH". after making  changes in internal table i called @refresh. This help me solve issue of refreshing whole grid. it refresh with only row which made changes.